# Lambda Calculus: terms without β-normal form, but have a β-normal form when combined?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I need to find two λ-terms $A$ and $B$ where neither $A$ nor $B$ have a β-normal form, but $(A\ B)$ has a β-normal form. How would I go about doing this?